# prevent gnome from running on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, gnome

i upgraded from 10.04 to 12.04 the other day, and now i get this warning in my syslog when i reboot:

```
Sep 19 17:42:48 myusername gnome-session[2251]: WARNING: Session 'ubuntu' runnable check failed: Exited with code 5
```

which i'm guessing is due to 12.04 using unity instead of gnome? i know this is only a warning, but i guess i should optimize the system and prevent it from trying to run gnome when it starts up?

i did some googling on this warning and found that for a lot of people this is associated with not being able to login - **note that this is not the case for me**. everything runs smoothly - i can login, use the web, run all my usual programs, etc.

please tell me if i should bother doing anything, and if so then what.

thanks!

Comment: take my adivse please remove this and install fresh installation of ubuntu 12.04 to avoid any problem in the future and if you wanna gnome not unity it's very easy just write this command " sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y ; sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-session-fallback -y && sudo reboot " this will install gnome 2 look like gnome in ubuntu 10.04 and this good choice and you won't meet any conflict between dependices

Comment: ah i don't think its worth a full re-install for me. nothing is broken - its just that i saw this warning message when checking if everything was ok after the upgrade in `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: ok try to full remove gnome and reinstall it may be this mistake appear because gnome classic replaced with gnome shell so try this enter tty be press ctrl + alt + f5 then write your name and password after that kill x by write " sudo service lightdm stop " the write remove command this " sudo mkdir -p ~/backup && sudo mv -v ~/.* ~/backup ; sudo apt-get purge gnome* -y ; sudo apt-get autoremove --purge -y ; sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop unity gnome-session-fallback xorg-xserver -y ; sudo reboot "  and after login choose gnome

Answer (score 0):

I experience this problem with some of my Ubuntu 12.04 GUI sessions.
For instance, earlier today, my TightVNC session failed with this error.

There is [a bug report on this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/959344), and the suggested remedy worked for me (as it did in previous cases):

```
sudo apt-get install unity-2d
```